Wedge of direct sum of line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$
Let $p\leq n$ and consider the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Why is
$$
\bigwedge\nolimits^p \mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus n} \cong \mathcal{O}(-p)^{{n \choose p}}?
$$

Do you know how the exterior power interacts with direct sums? This is featured in many linear or abstract algebra courses, for instance. (Totally fine if you don't.)

Well, we have $\bigoplus_{k=0}^n \left( \bigwedge\nolimits^k(V) \otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{n-k}(W) \right) \simeq \bigwedge\nolimits^n(V \oplus W)$. I don't see where the binomial coefficient comes in though.

Your above formula holds for $V\oplus W$ - what happens if you extend it to $V\oplus W \oplus X$? Or $V_1\oplus V_2\oplus V_3\oplus V_4$? (Say, as $V\oplus (W\oplus X)$?)

I get $\bigwedge\nolimits^p (V_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus V_n) \cong \bigoplus_{k_1=0}^p \bigoplus_{k_2=0}^{p-k_1} \cdots \bigoplus_{k_{n} = 0}^{p-k_1-\ldots-k_{n-1}} \left(\bigwedge\nolimits^{k_1} V_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{k_n} V_n\right)$.

Oh, OK, I think I see how it follows.

As per our discussion in the comments, $$\bigwedge^p (V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_n) \cong \bigoplus_{0\leq k_i, \sum_{i=1}^n k_i = p} \left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \bigwedge^{k_i} V_i\right).$$
Noting that $\bigwedge^p \mathcal{O}(-1)=0$ for $p>1$, we see that setting $V_1=\cdots=V_n=\mathcal{O}(-1)$, the only choices that give a nonzero direct summand are when $p$ of the $k_i$ are $1$ and the other $n-p$ of the $k_i$ are $0$. In that case, $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \bigwedge^{k_i} V_i=(\mathcal{O}(-1))^{\otimes p}\cong \mathcal{O}(-p)$, and there are $\binom{n}{p}$ ways to choose $k_i$ like that. So we arrive at the desired result: $\bigwedge^p \mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus n} \cong \mathcal{O}(-p)^{\oplus\binom{n}{p}}$.
